# Left floated list

Tags: css, list, position, css-float

I want to float lists (DL) left, like the image at the bottom of this post.

If i use this:

```
dl {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 50%;
}
```

...Then the lists, that a shorter than the long one, will be placed at the bottom of the long one. They will not continue after the above list.

[image: Design of the lists]

Can any of you guys tell me what i'm doing wrong??

Thank you in advance... :-)

Comment: Check whether the `dl` has any native padding or margin. Try setting both to `none`

Comment: It is difficult to say without more information but couldn't it be that the wrapper is too small?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you want is probably not possible with floats. AFAIK there are JavaScript solutions to this, however I can't seem to find them right now.

One thing you could try, if you don't mind not supporting IE is CSS columms. Drop your rule and use following instead

```
#parentElement { /* selector to the parent of your dl's */
  column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
}
```

Comment: It is, actually, quite possible with floats, and a handful of other CSS2 techniques. K.I.S.S.

Comment: This solution worked, in new browsers, if you combined it with the following: http://www.symphonious.net/2010/12/30/controlling-wrapping-in-css3-columns/